# ''dot plot'' relativo a média com desvio padrão

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

Bom dia

No gráfico anexado, os pontos são referentes ao valor da média de seletividade de cada espécie. 
Nesse gráfico, eu gostaria de:

1) ter tamanhos de fonte maiores dos pontos menores referentes à massa corporal <9Kg. Eu queria reduzir a escala de diferença entre os pontos, colocando os menores um pouco maiores, mas mantendo os outros maiores (espécies com massa corporal> 9Kg) no mesmo tamanho. Se não for possível, eu gostaria pelo menos de aumentar o tamanho da fonte dos pontos.

2) Gostaria também de adicionar uma borda preta ao redor dos pontos (só para destacar os pontos)

3) Eu gostaria de adicionar o desvio padrão (sd) de cada ponto médio. Os valores da média e desvio padrão são mostrados respectivamente nas colunas "media" e "sp".

Alguém poderia me ajudar? Desde já, obrigada :)

```js
library(tidyverse)
Dataset %>%
ggplot(aes(x = media, y = specie, 
             colour = energetic_level, size = log(bodymass))) +
  geom_point(alpha = .9) +
  scale_colour_continuous(low = 'green', high = 'red') +
  labs(x = 'media', y = 'Species') +
  ggthemes::theme_few() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = .5))
```

```html
media   dp  specie  bodymass    energetic_level
4.063478961 3.627269468 AAChlor_cyn 5000.01 3.2
4.05537378  3.585436083 ABOtol_cras 1206.61 2.4
3.999309751 3.818689333 ACMiop_tal  1248.86 3
3.945049659 3.855743536 BACerc_mit  5041.29 2.5
3.862515658 3.687924328 BCThry_swin 4000    2.8
3.655056928 3.732785731 DAHys_afri  14936.02    2.8
3.56041853  3.478167947 DBLep_cap   1500    3
3.402431689 3.446995588 DCCivet_civ 12075.58    4.6
3.401743858 3.569716116 FGenet_gen  1756.17 6.1
3.39029097  3.414370313 GALept_serv 11999.96    7
3.39009097  1.552336764 GBPhil_mont 4896.05 2.6
3.32029097  1.920646552 HOryct_afer 56175.2 5
3.239734182 3.540636613 IHipp_amph  1536310.4   3
3.154474564 3.526089786 JBSylv_grim 15639.15    3.2
2.883544415 3.007873613 MAPota_larv 69063.79    3.3
2.719993477 1.308813082 MBTrag_scri 43250.39    3
2.718552867 3.080761281 MCPant_pa   52399.99    7
1.982822501 2.085016316 MDRed_aru   58059.24    3
1.529854402 1.814623348 MFSync_caf  592665.98   3
1.443776834 1.254052861 NLox_afric  3824539.93  3
1.402107786 1.637998721 OCan_mes    22000   5.2
1.164299734 1.397597868 PPant_le    158623.93   6.8
0.887732043 1.318886523 QLyc_pict   21999.99    7
0.82952687  0.789227213 UCroc_croc  63369.98    7
0.782973623 0.570878282 VTrag_oryx  562592.69   2.7
0.477482615 0.624782141 YHipp_eq    264173.96   3
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Acredito que o código abaixo satisfaz tudo o que foi pedido:

```
Dataset %>%
ggplot(aes(x = media, y = specie)) +
  geom_point(aes(fill=energetic_level, size=log(bodymass)), alpha = .9, 
    pch=21, colour="black", stroke=2) +
  scale_fill_continuous(low = 'green', high = 'red') +
  labs(x = 'media', y = 'Species') +
  ggthemes::theme_few() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = .5)) +
  scale_size_continuous(range = c(3, 6)) +
  geom_errorbarh(aes(xmin=media-dp, xmax=media+dp), colour="black", size=.2)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora, vamos por partes ver como cada item foi obtido:

> 1) ter tamanhos de fonte maiores dos pontos menores referentes à massa corporal <9Kg. Eu queria reduzir a escala de diferença entre os pontos, colocando os menores um pouco maiores, mas mantendo os outros maiores (espécies com massa corporal> 9Kg) no mesmo tamanho. Se não for possível, eu gostaria pelo menos de aumentar o tamanho da fonte dos pontos.

Resolvi isso com a função `scale_size_continuous(range = c(3, 6))`. Nela eu determinei que o menor tamanho para os pontos é 3 e, o maior, 6. Assim, o menor ponto terá, no mínimo, metade da área do maior. Se a proporção não te agradou, basta alterar estes números para chegar num resultado mais esteticamente agradável. Perceba que a função `scale_size_continuous(range = c(3, 6))` mantém a transformação de logaritmo aplicada na `bodymass`.

> 2) Gostaria também de adicionar uma borda preta ao redor dos pontos (só para destacar os pontos)

Basta dizer que o símbolo a ser plotado é o `pch=21`. Para o `R`, isto significa um ponto redondo com borda. Com `colour` eu defino a cor da borda e com `stroke` a sua espessura. Coloquei uma espessura maior para deixar bem claro que ela existe.

> 3) Eu gostaria de adicionar o desvio padrão (sd) de cada ponto médio. Os valores da média e desvio padrão são mostrados respectivamente nas colunas "media" e "sp".

Faça isso utilizando a função `geom_errorbarh(aes(xmin=media-dp, xmax=media+dp), size=.2)`. Os limites da error bar foram definidos como média - desvio padrão e média + desvio padrão. A cor e a espessura das linhas são definidas com os argumentos `colour` e `size`, respectivamente.

Comment: Olá @Marcus isso mesmo. Eu tinha conseguido resolver, mas sua explicação foi excelente para eu entender melhor cada comando. Eu também add height=0 para que o a linha referente ao DP não ficasse com aquele traço na vertical ao final. 
geom_errorbarh(aes(xmax = media + dp, xmin = media - dp), color="grey60",height=0)

Comment: Excelente. Bom saber que tu conseguiu chegar no mesmo resultado que eu. Então, já que a minha resposta te ajudou de alguma maneira, aceite ela para que, no futuro, outras pessoas saibam que ela te ajudou de alguma forma.